# SP2013 - Blog Comment Count?

Tags: 2013, blog, content-search-web-part, cswp

I am trying to style a Content Search Web Part to pull in all the blogs across a specific site collection. I'm trying to pull the following information:

Blog site, author name (w/ presence), created date, number of comments, number of likes

I have all the information working so far except for the presence indicator and the number of comments. Any assistance on how I can get the number of comments for a specific blog post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to created a new Managed Property in Search that was mapped to `ows_NumComments`. Ran the full crawl, and it worked.